# PHP for loop, breaking

Tags: php, for-loop, break

I'm trying to have the loop stop before it reaches the designated number of repeats if the value being calculated is equal to another variable. I have a break in an *if* statement but it doesn't seem to do anything as it just continues to loop until it reaches the designated end value.

```
echo "<h4>iteration Stages</h4>\n";
// looping the math for each iteration
for ($i=1; $i <= $iterations ; $i++) { 
    $estimate = 0.5 * ($estimate + $number / $estimate);

        if ($estimate == $real){
            echo round($estimate, 2);
            break;

        } else {
            echo round($estimate, 2);
            echo " -- \n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, if it doesn't break, then that `$estimate == $real` condition is never met.

Comment: Maybe you should round your estimate before comparing...